# PostgreSQL product table and sales table

Tags: postgresql

I have the following problem.
I need all the products in a table and at the same time put the sum of the quantities sold of each product.

I need to see each product in the product table with the total sum of sales, according to the date range.
If there is no sales record in that range, it must be zero.

My query is as follows, but it doesn't work.

Product Table : sto_producto

Product sales movement table: sto_movdet

```
SELECT 
    sto_producto.pro_codprod AS cod_product,
    sto_producto.pro_desc AS name_product,
    sum(sto_movdet.mvd_cant) AS total_sale,
    AVG(sto_movdet.mvd_costo) AS cost_product_sale

FROM   sto_producto

INNER JOIN sto_movdet ON (sto_producto.pro_codprod = sto_movdet.mvd_codprod)

WHERE mvd_fecha BETWEEN '2020301' and '20200716'
GROUP BY pro_codprod, pro_desc
```

I expect a result similar to

```
cod_product  name_product  total_sale   cost_product_sale
0004         mousered          45         $ 2.355
0071         pc laptop          0         $ 1.000
```

Comment: Can you edit your question. Pls add how your table actually looks like and your expected result as table

Comment: From which table does the column `mvd_costo` come from?

Comment: hello the Postgres version is the most recent, it is not 9.3.There are two tables, one sto_product and another table called sto_movdet. Mvd_costo and mvd_cant are values ​​that are in table sto_movdet. attentive to your help. Thank you

Comment: How can you have a `cost_product_sale` value if there are no sales?

Comment: The cost_product_sale value is the cost of the product you have when selling it. What I need is to list all product (sto_product) and for each record in the sto_product table Bring me the sum of the quantity sold (mvd_cant) and the average cost (mvd_cost)

Comment: If a product was not sold, it should be zero in sales quantity (mvd_cant) and zero in cost (cost_product_sale).